# Recursively find all parent nodes for a given node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to write a cypher query where given a node X, it gives all the parent nodes for that given node until I find the root node which has the type attribute as ROOT.

As an example, I have attached below image where my RootNode is the main parent node and it has attribute *{type: "ROOT"}*.

[image]

> **Example1:** Find all parent nodes for a node with label *TYPE2:X3*
> From the graph we can see, TYPE2:X3 has one parent nodes TYPE2:X1. Now TYPE2:X1 has two parents TYPE1:T1 and RootNode. Recursively, finding parent of TYPE1:T1 which is RootNode. Hence, the answer will be **TYPE1:T1 and TYPE2:X1**

> **Example2:** Find all parent nodes for a node with label *TYPE2:X4*
> From the graph we can see, TYPE2:X4 has 4 parent nodes
> **TYPE1:T1, TYPE2:X1, TYPE2:X2, TYPE1:T2** who all have parent as RootNode so the answer will be these 4 nodes.

Please note that my graph can have upto 10 level of parent nodes like this.

Comment: I am unsure of your terminology. By "label" do you mean a neo4j [node label](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/appendix/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-labels)? If so, does the node "label" `TYPE2:X3` mean that the node actually has 2 labels (`TYPE2` and `T1`)? Also, how does one determine the "parent nodes" of node X? Do we just treat the end node of all outgoing relationships (or only specific relationship types) from X as "parent" nodes?

Comment: Yes here TYPE2:X3 means node has 2 labels TYPE2 and X3. For the second node. For the second question, Until we reach a node from where no outgoing nodes are there i.e its the root node or a node has type: "ROOT", we can stop there. Primarily for the second point we can consider no outgoing nodes as the parent node and stop there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED]

This query will return all distinct `ancestor` nodes by following all outbound relationships starting at a given `n` node, excluding any node that has no outbound relationships.

```
... // (prior Cypher providing n)

MATCH p = (n)-[*..8]->(root)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((root)-->())
UNWIND NODES(p)[1..-1] AS ancestor
RETURN DISTINCT ancestor
```

This query also puts an upper bound on the [variable length pattern](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength) to avoid taking forever or running out of memory.

The `x[1..-1]` syntax specifies a sublist of `x` consisting of its second element up to and including its next-to-last element. *(The [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/values-and-types/lists/#_list_range_and_size) is a bit misleading, as it concentrates on the `range()` function, whereas specifying a sublist does not depend on using the `range()` function at all. The 2 concepts should have been covered separately.)*

Comment: The problem is I don't know the end:RootNode, it can have any name.

Comment: Then how does one identify the root node? For instance, do all `worked_with` relationships point to the root node?

Comment: Once we reach a node with No outgoing nodes we can stop. And we are sure there is such a node.

Comment: Also TYPE2:X3 which you have used are also generated dynamically so we should somehow avoid it. Simply put given a node find all parents of all nodes linked to it until all parents reach a node which has no more outgoing nodes.

Comment: When you say "parent", do you mean "non-root ancestor"? That is, do you want all nodes between a given node at the root?

Comment: Yes, We are given a node and we have keep on finding parents for each of the node until we reach a node which has no parents. Its like searching, we have a stack, push node's parent inside the stack and repeat until the stack is empty. I need all those nodes which were placed within that stack.

Comment: Thanks , it worked. One question what is [1..-1] you have used

Comment: I have added a final paragraph on that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is just traverse the graph with variable path length:

```
match path = (s)-[*..9]->()-->(e)
where s:X4 and s:TYPE2 and e:ROOT
with [n in nodes(path) where n <> e | n] as parentnodes
return parentnodes
```

Variable path length can make the query explode, especially if you have supernodes. If you have a fairly balanced tree structure like in your diagram, this may be okay.

UPDATE:
This will make it so you don't need to know the label on the root node:

```
match path = (s)-[*..9]->()-->(e)
where s:X4 and S:TYPE2 and not (e)->()
with [n in nodes(path) where n <> e | n] as parentnodes
return parentnodes
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know the node names. Only name of node for which I want find all parents. Even relationships can be different as it can many nodes with different relationships. Only known items are the node name for which ancestors are to be found.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to not require knowing the label for the end node.

Comment: The problem is there can be any number of dynamically generated label names so we can't search with X4 , TYPE2 also. The only thing we know in graph is they have given a node with 2 labels ex TYPE2:X3  and there are other nodes in graph which can have any labels and we have to find all parents of TYPE2:X3 until we find a node with no parents.

Comment: Having a large number of dynamically generated labels is generally bad practice. The set of labels should be relatively stable. If those nodes all have pretty much the same set of properties and relationships, you should should consider just using a single label and adding a couple of extra properties to store the "TYPE1" and "X2" kinds of strings. You can [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/) those extra properties to find desired nodes quickly.

Comment: I can see your point @cybersam but the problem is these nodes all are dependencies actually. I have just showed a small piece but actually I can have millions of nodes which can have let us suppose Label1 from a set of 50 labels and label2 which can be anything. Also how index you mentioned help in searching?

Comment: [Indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/) allow the Cypher planner to generate operations that avoid having to scan every node when starting a query. They are less useful if you are already have the node(s) you want to work with.